Excel - Remove all text after the last found "."
In Excel I wanna remove everything in a cell after the last "."
The value 100.200.300.400 in a cell I wan't to be 100.200.300. in a new cell
The value 100.200.3.4 in a cell I wan't to be 100.200.3. in a new cell
I have tried different versions of the LEFT, RIGHT, and LEN, but it doesn't work 100% in my case so I'm doing something wrong.
It only works on the first cell using this formula:
 =LEFT(A2,LEN(A2) - SEARCH(".",A2))

Incorrect results:


Why isn't B4 100.200.3 and B5 100.20.3 ?

This should solve your problem : =TEXTBEFORE(A1:A4,".",-1) but your post statements and images posted are contradicting each other!

@MayukhBhattacharya The image appears to be demonstrating the erroneous output they are getting with their current code (provided at the end of the post), rather than an example of desired output.  (Their current code is always trimming 4 characters off the end, because the first "." appears as the 4th character from the start)  Slightly confusing, yes — it could certainly benefit from titles/captions

Oh I see what you mean. Also =REGEXREPLACE(A2:A5,".\d+$","") if you have it.

Or =REGEXREPLACE(A2:A5,"\d+$","") if you want to include the final decimal point.

For older Excel you could use this:
=LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-MATCH(".",MID(A2,LEN(A2)-ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,LEN(A2))),1),))
For current Excel:
=TEXTBEFORE(A2,".",-1)&"."

If using in Excel 2016, select the range for the result and enter in the first cell with Control + Shift + Enter:
=LEFT(A2:A5,FIND("!",SUBSTITUTE(A2:A5,".","!",3))-1)

Or to include .:
=VÄNSTER(A2:A5;HITTA("!";BYT.UT(A2:A5;".";"!";3)))

=LEFT(A2:A5,FIND("!",SUBSTITUTE(A2:A5,".","!",3)))



Thanks to  Chronocidal for suggesting a more resilient version:

To avoid wrong result when the "marker" (!) is already present in text, replace it with : first
Get the last position based of number of instances (instead of a fixed value)

=LEFT(
    A2:A5,
    FIND(
        "!",
        SUBSTITUTE(
            SUBSTITUTE(A2:A5, "!", ":"),
            ".",
            "!",
            LEN(A2:A5) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A5, ".", ""))
        )
    ) - 1
)


Nice solution in case the last dot would always be the 3rd (as in given samples).

Thanks P.b! I was going to add a calculation for the last one then stopped ;)

I thought SUBSTITUTE would make it a long formula, but it's the same size as mine actually using hardcoded row 1: =LEFT(A2,FIND("!",SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","!",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".",))))) and =LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-MATCH(".",MID(A2,LEN(A2)-ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A2))),1),)) shorter than the one I posted (but that won't break if row one would get deleted)

Also, I try to avoid fill-down as much as possible - I forgot often to fill-down when I update the formula ;)

A more resilient version that will support A) different numbers of dots, and B) text that contains exclamation marks: =LEFT(A2:A5, FIND("!", SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A5, "!", ":"), "." ,"!", LEN(A2:A5)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A5, ".", ""))))-1)

Thanks for kindly suggesting this @Chronocidal! I've added it to my answer.

Left of the Last Occurrence of a Character
Legacy Excel Using String Functions ('Building Plan')

Get the number of dots (the length of the string minus the length of the string without the dots):
nod=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))


Replace the last dot with e.g. a "@@":
rep=SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","@@",nod)


Get the position of the "@@" (last dot):
ldp=FIND("@@",rep)


Get the string to the left of the last dot inclusive:
=LEFT(A1,ldp)
(=LEFT(A1,ldp)-1 excludes the last dot)


Replace ldp:
=LEFT(A1,FIND("@@",rep))


Replace rep:
=LEFT(A1,FIND("@@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","@@",nod)))


Replace nod:
=LEFT(A1,FIND("@@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","@@",
    LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","")))))


Handle errors (Result):
=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND("@@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","@@",
    LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))))),"")



Once you acquire MS365, TEXTBEFORE will handle this easily as illustrated in P.b's answer.
